# char like '-' replaced with '???' on linux machine

Tags: java, linux

the file(HTML) content has special char like '-' replaced with '???' on linux machine.when i run same code on windows it's not replacing.

```
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
        for (String l : lines)
            out.println(l);
        out.close();
```

I have tried adding Unicode UTF-16,UTF-8 and iso-8859-1 not working

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-16");
```

On Windows machine special char like '-' replaced with 'â€“'

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems to be an encoding problem. Ensure that you are reading the file with the same encoding as you wrote it. How do you verify the file? Which editor?

Comment: Where do you see the â€?

Comment: I suggest you use UTF-8 on everything including any editor you use to view the file and you will be able to use any character.  When you see `â€` it is because you didn't use the same encoding as you wrote the file with.

Answer (score 2):

There are several dash symbols "–" and "-". They look similar, but they have different unicode value. Use the latter in the source code.

More dashes here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash . Your symbol is "en dash" `U+2013`, you should use "the standard ASCII hyphen" `U+002D`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by writing to file as the same encoding of the file

```
     InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));

        // now, write the file again with the changes
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file, r.getEncoding());
        for (String l : lines)
            out.println(l);
        out.close();
```

Comment: When reading or writing data, you should never rely on the default encoding. Always define or learn which encoding each file has and specify it when creating readers and writers!